# Unexpected destructor call when returning object from a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, return, destructor

I'm trying to recreate a priority queue implementation I made in C# to C++ as a project to jump into C++ with, but a lot of the nuance is tripping me up. The queue is designed as a template to work on any given class T. The queue will explicitly work with a struct representing objects called Priority Pairs: a pointer to a T object and an associated priority value (int).

The goal of this is to allow the actual objects (the T's) being compared in the queue to be completely separate and only ever be pointed to. I probably don't explicitly need the struct to accomplish this but this is how I'm doing it.

The important bits from the queue implementation:

```
template <class T>
class PriorityQueue
{
public:
    PriorityQueue(const int maxSizeIn)
    {
        maxSize = maxSizeIn;
        queueArray = new PriorityPair<T>*[maxSize];
        currentHeapSize = 0;
    }
    ~PriorityQueue()
    {
        cout << "Destroy Queue with size: " << currentHeapSize << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentHeapSize; i++)
        {
            delete (PriorityPair<T>*)queueArray[i];
        }
        delete[] queueArray;
}
private:
    PriorityPair<T>** queueArray;
```

The Struct for PriorityPair:

```
template <class T>
struct PriorityPair
{
    PriorityPair(int valueIn, T* objectIn)
    {
        _PriorityValue = valueIn;
        _Object = objectIn;
    };

    ~PriorityPair()
    {
         cout << "Destroy Pair for object :(" << *_Object << "):  << endl;
    }

    int _PriorityValue;
    T* _Object;
};
```

During the course of my testing, I've found that calling my PeekTop method seems to cause a PriorityPair to have its destructor called. My best guess is that I am accidentally creating a temporary one due to a failure to understand some nuance of the language.

Here's the peek method:

```
    T PeekTop()
    {
        if (IsEmpty())
            return nullptr;
        else
            return *((PriorityPair<T>)(*queueArray[0]))._Object; 
    }
```

Additionally, here is the insert operation (minimally effective insert, does no heap/queue operations):

```
    int InsertElement(PriorityPair<T>* elementIn)
    {
        //do not insert nulls --
        if (elementIn == nullptr)
            return -2;
        //we could user std::vector or manually expand the array, but a hard max is probably sufficient
        if (currentHeapSize == maxSize)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        //insert the pointer to the new pair element in at the index corresponding to the current size, then increment the size
        queueArray[currentHeapSize++] = elementIn;
        return 0;
    }
```

In the main I have the following:

```
PriorityQueue<string> queue = PriorityQueue<string>(10);
string s1 = "string1";
int code = queue.InsertElement(new PriorityPair<string>(5, &s1));
string i = queue.PeekTop();
cout << "-------\n";
cout << i << endl;
```

This appears to work, insofar that it does insert the element correctly, but I don't understand if that new pair is behaving as I intend it to. When I run the code the destructor for my Priority Pair is getting called twice. This happens specifically when the function PeekTop is called. Once during the queue's lifetime and once when the queue goes out of scope and is destroyed.

Here is the output from the above code:

```
Code: 0
Destroy Pair for object :(string1): with priority :(5):
-------
string1
Destroy Queue with size: 1
Destroy Pair for object :(): with priority :(5):
```

The first destructor call shows the string correctly with its value, but in the second we can see that the string itself has gone out of scope (which is fine and expected).

Comment: Names that begin with underscore-capitals are reserved for the implementation; your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: This `_Object;`, along with all identifiers that begin with an underscore and an upper-case character, or ones that contain two consecutive underscores,  is reserved in C++ for the implementation. You are not allowed to create such names yourself. And names like `_Object` are quite likely to be used by the implementation.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. What is `queue.InsertElement`? Also, I don't see any `delete`s being done, were they removed to create shorter example?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I apologize, I had a page refresh incident and the relevant functions (that I added after realizing they were obviously relevant) apparently weren't saved and I did not realize. I will edit and correct that.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was unaware of this. It doesn't seem to be explicitly causing errors during compilation or runtime but I will change those immediately.

Comment: @Caboose: The wonders of not following the rules are that you don't necessarily get told your mistakes, until perhaps you have shipped a million units and the law suits start coming in. In that sense, programming C++ is a lot harder than taking maths tests in school :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB I suppose that is the folly of coming from languages like C#, where you are explicitly told when you are using disallowed naming conventions.

Comment: Why all the manual memory management (`new`/`delete`)? Why not use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr`)? Are you living in a pre-C++11 world?

Comment: C++ is a cut to the bone, you don't need it, you don't get charged world. End result is a nasty surprise lurking around every corner that you don't look around first. There is almost always no checking to make sure you didn't do something silly. For example, the default behaviour for running off the end of an array is "Sucks to be you".

Comment: @user4581301 This is neither true nor helpful. There are reasons to use low-level fast languages like C and C++, and those missing checks can take time which many applications (games, video, robotics, device drivers, …) simply cannot afford. Yes, in a lot of cases a higher-level language is the right tool for the job, but in a lot of cases it isn’t. You don’t know why the OP is trying to learn C++.

Comment: "C++ is a cut to the bone"  tldr - I know nothing about C++.

Comment: @JesperJuhl In short, I don't want to. This is something of an excercise born from curiosity. I want to know how to best handle raw pointers, and I seem to be seriously missing something here.

Comment: Why the cast in `*((PriorityPair<T>)(*queueArray[0]))._Object`? Your `queueArray` already holds elements of type `PriorityPair<T>`. Since I don't the _exact_ reason for why it is happening I won't post the answer, but _the cast, itself, creates a temporary_. In addition, your example isn't still complete due to missing `IsEmpty`, `maxSize`, and `currentHeapSize`, but those additions were straightforward.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The casting seemed to be necessary to get the object. QueueArray holds elements of type `PriorityPair<T>*` not `PriorityPair<T>`. Could that be my problem?

Comment: @Caboose _Seemed_, or _was_? Yes, `queueArray` is a pointer to `PriorityPair<T>*`, but `*queueArray[0]` is already of type `PriorityPair<T>`, since it contains 2 dereferences: `queueArray[0]` returns `PriorityPair<T>*`, and `*` at the front of the expression - dereferences it to `PriorityPair<T>`. And, with removed cast, your `return` statement may look like: `return *(*queueArray[0])._Object;`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think I'm having Intellisense issues. That does work (and fixes the multiple calls to the destructor) but without the cast it doesn't shop up with Intellisense. Now, why does the cast change the behaviour?

Comment: @DanielH It's mostly true and very helpful. I'll pass on defending "Cut to the Bone" since the existence of C proves my hyperbole wrong right there. I don't know why OP is learning C++. I don't need to know. But OP does need to know early that a lot of the knowledge they are bringing in from C# does not apply for the very reason you list: runtime hand-holding takes time. The volume of questions that can be distilled to "Why wasn't an exception thrown over obvious programming error X?" shows that people aren't born knowing this tidbit, program accordingly, and get nasty surprises.

Comment: @DanielH I'm just having problems with the languages nuances :) I've done my fair share of assembly language programming so I understand the concept of letting go of high-level language preconceptions.

Comment: @Caboose And that's why I didn't post the answer :) I don't know the exact reason _why_ it is happening, I just described _what_ is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the names starting with an underscore, which as people have pointed out in the comments, your problem appears to be in the line `return *((PriorityPair<T>)(*queueArray[0]))._Object`. Let’s look at this piece by piece, from the inside and working our way out.

`queueArray` is a `PriorityPair<T>**`, as declared in `PriorityQueue`. This could be read as “pointer to pointer to `PriorityPair<T>`”, but in your case it looks like you mean it to be “raw array of pointer to `PriorityPair<T>`”, which is also a valid reading. So far so good.

`queueArray[0]` is a `PriorityPair<T>*&`, or “reference to pointer to `PriorityPair<T>`”. References are pretty invisible in C++, and this just means you’re dealing with the actual first element of the array and not a copy. Again, this is a reasonable thing to ask for when trying to peek at the top of the queue.

`*queueArray[0]` is simply a `PriorityPair<T>&`, or “reference to `PriorityPair<T>`”. Again, the reference here just means you’re dealing with the actual thing being pointed to by `queueArray[0]`, and not a copy.

`(PriorityPair<T>)(*queueArray[0])` is a `PriorityPair<T>`, the result of casting the one you already had to a new one. **This creates a temporary `PriorityPair<T>`, which is the one you see destroyed later**. There is no programmatic reason to do this cast (your IntelliSense issues are a different question and I don’t know enough about VS to comment about them); it’s already the right type. You can verify that it’s a different one that’s destroyed if you add `this` to the output, since `this` is a pointer to the current object and a temporary would need to live somewhere else in memory.

`((PriorityPair<T>)(*queueArray[0]))._Object` is a `T*`, or “pointer to `T`”. In fact, it points to the `T` that was stored for the top of the priority queue, which is good.

And finally, the full expression `*((PriorityPair<T>)(*queueArray[0]))._Object` dereferences this to give a `T`, and the return statement returns a *copy of* that `T`. This isn’t affecting the behavior you’re seeing, but if you added destructor calls to the objects you tested with, it would. It would probably be more efficient to return a reference to the `T`, which would forgo the copying, by changing the return type from `T` to `T&` or `T const&`.

Other issues I noticed, not related to this question, which you might find useful when learning C++ (not a comprehensive list; I mostly wasn’t looking for these):

- Both of your constructors should use [initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and have empty bodies (yes, `new` expressions can go in initializer lists, I think literally everybody I’ve spoken to about it either asked this the first time or assumed incorrectly, including me). This will somewhat more efficient and much more idiomatic.
- You don’t need to implement a destructor for the `PriorityPair` (except for learning the nuances of the language); it’s what’s known as a Plain Old Data (POD) type. If you wanted the `PriorityPair`’s destruction to `delete` the `T`s you would need that, but you want the `T`s to be managed completely separately.
- As people pointed out in the comments, [you aren’t allowed to use those identifier names yourself](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) in case the compiler or standard library want them. This *might* be fine, it *might* cause problems for you at compile time, or it *might* appear to work correctly but send all your users’ browser history and emails to their parents and/or employers. That last is unlikely, but the C++ standard doesn’t forbid it; this is what undefined behavior means. Other allowed behaviors are creating a black hole to destroy the Earth and [shooting demons out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), but these are even less likely in practice.
- I *think* like you have the destructor logic for `PriorityQueue` correct, and it’s easy to mess that sort of thing up. Congratulations!

Comment: It's also worth noting that the current implementation only works if `nullptr` is convertible to your `T`. If you want the option to return something for an empty queue, just returning a `T*` (which may be `nullptr`) would make more sense.

Comment: Thank you, this is the exact type of response I was looking to see. It seems a big part of my problem was just the Intellisense, but as a consequence I learned the implications of casting like that. The bit about returning T& instead is also helpful and closer to what I intended to do. Can you comment on why it is better to use initializer lists? My naive guess was that they would behave no differently than my current implementation.

Comment: Good breakdown. Question can't really be answered in its current state, but worth the upvote.

Comment: @Useless I actually was curious about that. The behavior in C# is well defined and easy to understand/deal with when returning null, but less so here. I was sort of ignoring that until I dealt with my other more pressing issues.

Comment: Initializer lists are where the members and base classes are initially constructed. In the body, you’re assigning the members, but they’ve already been constructed; the old values are overwritten/deleted/whatever else is done in `operator=`. For POD types, default initialization does nothing and they’re pretty much equivalent, but this isn’t true of all types. If you have a type where default initialization does something expensive and the work will be thrown away when you assign in the body, it makes a big difference.